# How to set password policy without using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, passwords, password-policy

I am trying to develop one new feature in my rails application in which admin user can set different password policy for each company. Policies may have some of the rules like, User should change the password after some time interval, User cannot use same password again,admin can set some standard for password, etc.

I am using mongoDB in my application.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **User cannot use same password again** is a little harsh, because you have to store every historical password digest of every user. Note that there can be collision in password digests, so even though the user entered a brand new password, the digest still has a slight chance to be identical to one of his used passwords.

Comment: Yes I agree with you there may be collision in hash but the chances are very rare so I am neglecting it as of now...